# Impossible cube maybe

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

## Problem

Given an input `a` where a is a truthy/falsy value output the exact impossible cube below if truthy and the exact normal cube below if falsey.

Input `truthy`:

```
         ___________________________________
        / _______________________________  /|
       / / _____________________________/ / |
      / / /| |                         / /  |
     / / / | |                        / /   |
    / / /| | |                       / / /| |
   / / / | | |                      / / / | |
  / / /  | | |                     / / /| | |
 / /_/___| | |____________________/ / / | | |
/________| | |_____________________/ /  | | |
| _______| | |____________________ | |  | | |
| | |    | | |___________________| | |__| | |
| | |    | |_____________________| | |____| |
| | |   / / _____________________| | |_  / /
| | |  / / /                     | | |/ / /
| | | / / /                      | | | / /
| | |/ / /                       | | |/ /
| | | / /                        | |   /
| | |/_/_________________________| |  /
| |______________________________| | /
|__________________________________|/
```

Input `falsy`:

```
         ___________________________________
        / _______________________________  /|
       / / _____________________________/ / |
      / / /| |                         / /  |
     / / / | |                        / /   |
    / / /| | |                       / / /| |
   / / / | | |                      / / / | |
  / / /  | | |                     / / /| | |
 / /_/___|_|_|____________________/ / / | | |
/__________________________________/ /  | | |
| ________________________________ | |  | | |
| | |    | | |___________________| | |__| | |
| | |    | |_____________________| | |____| |
| | |   / / _____________________| | |_  / /
| | |  / / /                     | | |/ / /
| | | / / /                      | | | / /
| | |/ / /                       | | |/ /
| | | / /                        | |   /
| | |/_/_________________________| |  /
| |______________________________| | /
|__________________________________|/
```

## Rules

- Trailing whitespace allowed.
- Trailing newlines allowed.
- truthy/falsey values may be swapped (truthy for real cube and falsey for impossible cube)
- Input style should be specified
- **Shortest code in bytes wins**

Comment: Do we need to output that exact cube or any impossible cube?

Comment: @dzaima the exact cube.

Comment: At first glance, I thought the input was the ASCII art. *sigh of relief*

Comment: @Arnauld that would end up being pretty trivial, because you could just look at one character at a specific location and tell the two apart.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam True. What I had in mind was more like _"take any similar input of any size and figure out whether the cube is valid or not"_.

Comment: @Arnauld Go for it: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1 :P

Comment: can I swap the truthy/falsy outputs? (truthy: possible, falsy: impossible)

Comment: @dzaima Doesn't look like I would be undermining already posted answers so go ahead.

Comment: Should this get tagged kolmogorov-complexity?

Comment: @stannius Thought about it, but I am not sure.

Comment: @LiefdeWen me either, which is why I commented instead of attempting to add the tag myself :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 145 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
─3n{_⁰
ā"¹K╚=+ƨψ≡tšÆA%εW#žt─M^_ξ0“6²⁰ _*ž}"⁵æκLνbΡ°■=μθΝv╝xxΛTγ►℮ΞyF“'№⁰┐∙ž}"⁸Βλμž╚⅔\Ρ═⁴-θ=╚_>◄4℮`ε║t“'¦⁰ā;∫0 /ž}╬5}'Æ6«@┐2Ο3∙:Aža.?X"≥YΤ%‘5n}L9ž
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=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__,inputs=MA__)
This program stores the line data as 3 separate base 36-46 numbers and decodes each and `ž`s the values in the main array.
Because of the abusive way of how I draw the diagonal lines, the output has 27 lines of lines with spaces (which is allowed by the OP)

input:
0 - impossible
1 - possible

Explanation:

```
The first line is basically a substitute ⁰ with ─3n{_

ā                   push an empty array (the canvas for the whole cube)
 "...“              pushes 29714643711764388252557994982458231735529743027583646902
      6²─           base-36 decodes it
         3n{     }  for each group of 3 numbers do (where the numbers are X, Y, length)
            _         put all the contents on the stack (in the order X, Y, length)
              _*      get POP amount of underscores
                ž     in the canvas at the positions x;y (the position of the 1st char, 1-indexed) put the underscores

"...“             pushes 19564601770087915522037775830252836261712294966673526596188
     '№─          base-46 decodes it
        3n{    }  for each group of 3 numbers do
           _        put all the contents on the stack
            ┐∙      get an array of "|"s with the length of POP
              ž     in the canvas at the position x;y (position of the top char, 1-indexed) put the vertical bar

"...“                    pushes 124633728256573776407884156928319785312464662536125755768
     '¦─                 base-40 decodes it
        3n{           }  for each group of 3 numbers do
           _               put all the contents on the stack
            ā;             one below the stack put an empty array (canvas for the diagonal line)
              ∫    }       for range(length) do
               0             TMP
                 /           push "/"
                  ž          at the position (iter; 0), 1-indexed put a "/". This extends the array one line upward and causes the extra spaces.
                    ╬5     in the canvas at the position x;y(1-indexed, the top position) put the diagonal line canvas without overriding with spaces

'Æ             push 36
  6«           push 12
    @┐2Ο       push two spaces, encased in vertical bars - "| | |"
        3∙     get an array of 3 of those
          :A   save on variable A
            ž  in the canvas, at the positions 36; 12 put the array

a                 push the variable A
 .?         }     if the input is non-0, then
   X                remove the variable A off of the stack
    "≥YΤ%‘          push "|_|_|__________"
          5n        chop that into an array of strings of length 5
             L9ž  at positions 10;9 insert the top of stack (either the ["| | |","| | |","| | |"] or ["|_|_|","_____","","_____"]) in the canvas
```

Comment: How does it change based on input?

Comment: 0 - impossible, 1 - possible

Comment: Shouldn't an input of `1` result in the same output as other truthy inputs like `"test"`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan should it? In SOGL a truthy _number_ input is a non-0 number. Typing `test` in the input box results to an error. If its that big of a problem I could just make it take string input where "" would be falsy and everything else truthy

Comment: Oh right, I guess if the language is strongly typed then handling any type of input may be out of scope.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>187</s>  166 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḣ9;⁾| ṁ5¤oµ€“µ½¿‘¦
“ _/ |/|”;€⁶;”_ṁ"“¡ẇḞ6’D¤ṃ@“Ė⁸ġṾṗ¢œƝṇRK⁹ṄẸŒÐ¤ɓḂı)ḥṆqƓị¹÷ḄƝṁPʠVW1JĊTc;[¤ÆWŒṠṬ#ʋÆ6ẉ⁷ZḷƊḤƑẹẠGḊ|qi×Ƭ®ÐėƁ1(⁸ṪU¹Bgoƭ<Gḋ×c:ȦṚƇĊ¬e*⁽%ḷİ°U’Fs27Ç¹⁸?x€15¦€19Y
```

A full program.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##FY/PSgJRFMb3PYUUQbUxAw2boIgoqE1EJdXChUgUgkibglnMNXFo3JhCU5GhNbkIC1uY90xocO44lG9x7otMd1bn3/f7ON9ZNpe7DALiL0lNsqEeIWBxdPLYk8WONB6xhwP8kcYdtifUGElHI3pUl0ZDC@/sS1NtWjGTobZFrkn8KSGN@3V0CK5W1da7lYx7LYIhgY3Po7rfIDB3tyUDghK5fFQTVXT@6sSL3ucs8VeCcsGv03cFQfSJl0KA7YybB6nYlmftZbRjdEQ5NaoRNAk6U@OKKCfIvZasf0S871vEHf@GXCC3uUnc0gunwvY7@CGqnu2z2Ix6iOBtH2HtJO@/LytNRdiZpd82wYNvehZ2snOSDaaVmdfF7r7Ks3G@sChMBIWuXKjosTi2w5I8DIJg/h8)

#### How?

103 bytes are a 101 digit base 250 number, which is a base-8 compression of a possible cube, with trailing spaces added to equalise the row-lengths, without new lines, and without 18 characters from the middle of each row, like this, but without newlines:

```
         _________________ 
        / _____________  /|
       / / ___________/ / |
      / / /| |       / /  |
     / / / | |      / /   |
    / / /| | |     / / /| |
   / / / | | |    / / / | |
  / / /  | | |   / / /| | |
 / /_/___|_|_|__/ / / | | |
/________________/ /  | | |
| ______________ | |  | | |
| | |    | | |_| | |__| | |
| | |    | |___| | |____| |
| | |   / / ___| | |_  / / 
| | |  / / /   | | |/ / /  
| | | / / /    | | | / /   
| | |/ / /     | | |/ /    
| | | / /      | |   /     
| | |/_/_______| |  /      
| |____________| | /       
|________________|/
```

The 8 base-8 digits represent the strings of characters:

```
1      2    3    4    5    6        7        0
"   ", "_", "/", " ", "|", "/ / /", "| | |", "_____"
```

So the compression is then like the below where `1`s, `6`s, `7`s and `0`s are to be replaced by the strings shown above:

```
111000__111/ 00___  /|11 / / 00_/ / |116| |11 / /  |1  6 | |11/ /1|1 671  6| |16 71 6 | |  6  7167 6___|_|_|__6 7/000_/ /  7| 00____ | |  771 7_7__771 | |___7____| |71/ / ___7_  / / 7  6176  7 61 7 / /1761  7/ /1 7 / /11| |1/1  7/_/0__| |  /11| |00__| | /11 |000_|/11
```

The program reverses the process and changes the characters that need changing if the cube should be an impossible one:

```
“ _/ |/|”;€⁶;”_ṁ"“¡ẇḞ6’D¤ṃ@“ ... ’Fs27Ç¹⁸?x€15¦€19Y  Main link: V
                                                     ...splitting this up...
                                                     ...Main link part 1:
“ _/ |/|”;€⁶;”_ṁ"“¡ẇḞ6’D¤ - make the list of strings of characters
“ _/ |/|”                 - list of characters = " _/ |/|"
           ⁶              - literal space character
         ;€               - concatenate €ach -> ["  ","_ ","/ ","  ","| ","/ ","| "]
             ”_           - literal = '_'
            ;             - concatenate -> ["  ","_ ","/ ","  ","| ","/ ","| ", '_']
                        ¤ - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                 “¡ẇḞ6’   -   base 250 literal = 31111555
                       D  -   convert to decimal list -> [3,1,1,1,1,5,5,5]
                "         - zip with:
               ṁ          -   mould like
                          -   -> ["   ","_","/"," ","|","/ / /","| | |","_____"]

                                                     ...Main link, part 2:
...ṃ@“ ... ’Fs27 - make the rows of a possible cube without the middle repetitions:
...              - part 1, above
     “ ... ’     - the 101 digit base 250 number
   ṃ@            - base decompression with swapped @rguments
            F    - flatten (because the digit values we are using are actually lists)
             s27 - split into chunks of length 27 (into the rows)

                                                     ...Main link part 3:
...Ç¹⁸?x€15¦€19Y - make "impossible" if need be, add the row middles and output
...              - part 2, above
       ?         -  if:
      ⁸          -    chain's left argument = V
   Ç             - ...then: call last link (1) as a monad
                 -          (make it an impossible cube - see link 1, below)
    ¹            - ...else: identity (do nothing)
            €    - for €ach
         ¦       - apply sparsely:
       15        - ...to index: 15
     x€    19    - ...this: repeat €ach nineteen times
               Y - join with newlines
                 - implicit print

ḣ9;⁾| ṁ5¤oµ€“µ½¿‘¦  Link 1, replace characters to make impossible: rows
                 ¦  apply sparsely:
            “µ½¿‘   ...to indexes: code-page indexes = [9,10,11]
                    ...this:
          µ€          for €ach:
ḣ9                      head to index 9
        ¤               nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
   ⁾|                     list of characters = ['|',' ']
      ṁ5                  mould like 5 = ['|',' ','|',' ','|']
  ;                     concatenate
         o              logical or (vectorises) with the row
                          (which has the effect of appending the rest of the row)
```

Comment: I "fattened" the cube on purpose and you took advantage of it +1.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6),  <s>352</s>   <s>344</s>  333 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @YairRand*

```js
x=>[...'mnopqrstuvwxyz01~'].reduce((p,c)=>(l=p.split(c)).join(l.pop()),`1yup
1z uux z|
1/z uu_/z |
yqswtqvy|
yys wtyvq|
qs0t sw
ys 0ts w
 snt/v0
v_/x${x?0:'|_|_|'}m/v 0
/~_${b=x?0:'o_'}p/zn
| ~${b}m wnrynuo_0__0ryywp0owryv p0_ vr st0/vrst 0vr/vtn/zrvtqwyzr/_/pow z
wuu__wz
|um|/~xo1yyq0w |z /q o__w| |szp~t111svzr
0qy pu~ox_ny0muxx`)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

x=>[...'mnopqrstuvwxyz01~'].reduce((p,c)=>(l=p.split(c)).join(l.pop()),`1yup
1z uux z|
1/z uu_/z |
yqswtqvy|
yys wtyvq|
qs0t sw
ys 0ts w
 snt/v0
v_/x${x?0:'|_|_|'}m/v 0
/~_${b=x?0:'o_'}p/zn
| ~${b}m wnrynuo_0__0ryywp0owryv p0_ vr st0/vrst 0vr/vtn/zrvtqwyzr/_/pow z
wuu__wz
|um|/~xo1yyq0w |z /q o__w| |szp~t111svzr
0qy pu~ox_ny0muxx`)

flag = true
setInterval(_ => o.innerHTML = f(flag = !flag), 750)
```

```html
<pre id=o></pre>
```

Comment: Removing `a=` and replacing the one reference to it with `0` (which it always equals when referenced) saves two bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 188 bytes

```
__¶____¶_¶↙¹↓↑⁷↗³Ｐ↓⁶↗²↓↓⁷←↙⁴↓↓↓↙↗⁸↑¹²←Ｐ←×_³⁵↓↙⁹↑←×_³⁴Ｐ↗⁹↓↓¹¹↗→×_³⁴↑¹¹↖Ｐ←×_²⁹↗⁷←Ｐ←×_³¹↙←×_²⁹↓↙⁶↑←_Ｐ↗⁷↓↘Ｐ↓⁹←←Ｐ×_³²↓↓⁹↗→×_³⁰Ｐ↑⁹↖←×_²⁷↗⁶←←↙⁵↘→→↗⁵ＵＯ²¹±²_↗↗Ｐ×_¹⁹←↙|←Ｐ↑²←←↑²ＦＮＵＯ⁵±³ |↑↑Ｐ↑⁴Ｆ²«→→Ｐ↑⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNCsIwEIWv4hG8UShuXAiC626yybpRMO0FuhH8STU10FW8SS7QI9SZl8YfGErz5s33Mlmti91qW2ymSYjghMA3uKia4KM6RKWj7KMyoRuHKwvS8cmid0CvInOU91nhasgS5ZOGg2drhdnqZUToonzMHumZ/pHvMBnIjKFRz2e1z4bEI/H45Vn4TbrITwzbmj9PynQpU@SwHo06L@exDoMS5bPn/1Wu8GvIx29KD6RLDMTRrjWNoaj1GAeqS7C0xy1YAaiZ03yOb8q8i8broeh3HNpxOCcEsYjQLUrso/N96BFbop9SZlbdNC3f) Link is to falsy version; change the input from `0` to `1` for the truthy version. Here is the approximate verbose code for the above program:

```
Print("__\n____\n_\n");
```

Print the part of the back visible through the right "hole".

```
Print(:DownLeft, 1);
Move(:Down);
Print(:Up, 7);
Print(:UpRight, 3);
Multiprint(:Down, 6);
Print(:UpRight, 2);
Move(:Down);
Print(:Down, 7);
Move(:Left);
Print(:DownLeft, 4);
```

Print the right "hole".

```
Move(3, :Down);
Move(:DownLeft);
Print(:UpRight, 8);
Print(:Up, 12);
Move(:Left);
Multiprint(:Left, Times("_", 35));
Move(:Down);
Print(:DownLeft, 9);
Move(:Up);
Print(:Left, Times("_", 34));
Multiprint(:UpRight, 9);
Move(:Down);
Print(:Down, 11);
Move(:UpRight);
Print(Times("_", 34));
Print(:Up, 11);
```

Print the outer edge of the cube.

```
Move(:UpLeft);
Multiprint(:Left, Times("_", 29));
Print(:UpRight, 7);
Move(:Left);
Multiprint(:Left, Times("_", 31));
Move(:DownLeft);
Print(:Left, Times("_", 29));
Move(:Down);
Print(:DownLeft, 6);
Move(:Up);
Print(:Left, "_");
Multiprint(:UpRight, 7);
```

Print the top "hole" of the cube.

```
Jump(1, 2);
Multiprint(:Down, 9);
Move(2, :Left);
Multiprint(Times("_", 32));
Move(:Down);
Print(:Down, 9);
Move(:UpRight);
Print(Times("_", 30));
Multiprint(:Up, 9);
Move(:UpLeft);
Print(:Left, Times("_", 27));
```

Print the front "hole" of the cube.

```
Print(:UpRight, 6);
Move(2, :Left);
Print(:DownLeft, 5);
Jump(3, 1);
Print(:UpRight, 5);
Oblong(21, Negate(2), "_");
Move(2, :UpRight);
Multiprint(Times("_", 19));
Move(:Left);
Print(:DownLeft, "|");
Move(:Left);
Multiprint(:Up, 2);
Move(2, :Left);
Print(:Up, 2);
```

Print the part of the back visible through the front "hole".

```
for (InputNumber()) Oblong(5, Negate(3), " |");
```

Make the cube impossible if necessary.

```
Move(2, :Up);
Multiprint(:Up, 4);
for (2) {
    Move(2, :Right);
    Multiprint(:Up, 6);
}
```

Print the part of the back visible through the top "hole".