# The Top Ten Elements You Won't BELIEVE Are In This Array

Tags: code-golf, array

AKA: Generate Clickbait From an Array.

Given an array of integers, generate some cringe-worthy clickbait based on its arrangement and length:

- If it's 20 elements or less, you can make a Top X List. *Parameters: length of the array.*
- Prime numbers are celebrities, so anytime two of them are next to each other it'll pass as gossip. *Parameters: the two adjacent primes in the order they appear in the array.*
- If any number appears twice or more in the array, then it's shocking and unbelievable and everyone needs to hear about it. If multiple numbers appear twice, make a news story for each one. Only print this once per unique number. *Parameters: occurrence of the number measured by total appearance.*
- If you see 3+ elements in <s>sorted</s> [monotonically increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Increasing_and_decreasing) order, followed by a sudden decrease, then tell of how they're sorted and tease about what happens next. Only do this once per straight. *Parameters: length of the straight.*

These are the respective clickbaits you should use:

```
The Top {{N}} Array Elements
{{N1}} And {{N2}} Were Spotted Together, You Won't Believe What They Did
These {{N}} Elements Will Blow Your Mind
{{N}} Elements Sort Themselves, Find Out What Comes Next
```

Remember, you represent a cheap media company, so you'll need to milk this and print every possible title. If there are 2 identical titles, print them both.

For example, if you're given this array…

```
1,2,3,4,2,1,1,5,6
```

You should output all of these, in arbitrary order:

```
The Top 9 Array Elements
2 And 3 Were Spotted Together, You Won't Believe What They Did
These 2 Elements Will Blow Your Mind
These 3 Elements Will Blow Your Mind
4 Elements Sort Themselves, Find Out What Comes Next
```

Note the *lack* of this title:

```
3 Elements Sort Themselves, Find Out What Comes Next
```

As code golf, the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: _"3+ consecutive increasing elements, followed by a sudden decrease"_ What's the expected result for `[ 2 3 4 4 ]`?

Comment: @Arnauld there's no sudden decrease there, so just print the first 3 titles.

Comment: Shouldn't "These 2 Elements Will Blow Your Mind" appear twice (once for `1` and once for `2`)?

Comment: Usually I don't downvote, but -1 for solely creating a challenge just to use a click-bait title and a completely unnecessary output format for a challenge of type "do A, B and C, oh and also D". You should really read [*Things to avoid when writing challenges*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges).

Comment: @JonathanAllan `2` appears twice so "These 2 Elements...", `1` appears three times so "These 3 Elements...". If `1` only appeared twice then you would be correct.

Comment: @BMO Maybe you should read the sandbox more often. This was on there for a considerable duration, when you might have voiced your opinions. Also, many challenges on this site use clickbait, it's not like this is the only challenge to do so lol

Comment: @KamilDrakari`1` may appear three times, but it still appears twice!

Comment: @JonathanAllan "if there are 2 identical titles, print them both."

Comment: What exactly qualifies as a sudden decrease? Can it just be a decrease of `1` or does it have to be something larger?

Comment: 2,3,2 will output in twice the prime gossip, or 2,3,1,2,3 (two primes two times)

Comment: There are enough edge cases that I suggest you write a reference implementation that demonstrates the exact logic answers should follow.

Comment: @DanielIndie I asked this and it was clarified by adding "the two adjacent primes in the order they appear in the array" and "print every possible title" (so yes, `2,3,2` and `2,3,1,2,3` will both output two prime gossip clickbaits).

Comment: @ConorO'Brien: Probably I should, if I saw it there I'd voiced my opinion there. But I thought I'd give a reason for my downvote because silently downvoting is of no use to anyone. About the click-bait, I think there's a massive difference between a catchy title for a good challenge and a challenge that's only been made for using a click-bait title.

Comment: I'm assuming only positive integers `> 0` are part of the input-array? Didn't see it in any rule nor comment yet.

Comment: For the example `[1,2,3,4,2,1,1,5,6]`, shouldn't the gossip `N Elements Sort Themselves, Find Out What Comes Next` be outputted twice, once with `N=4` for `[1,2,3,4]` and once with `N=3` for `[1,5,6]`? If not for the second, the term/Wikipedia-link for 'monotonically increasing' is incorrect. If it's indeed incorrect, should only increasing sequences by 1, like `[1,2,3]` or `[5,6,7]` be correct, or also by any `k` other than 1, like `[1,3,5]` or `[6,9,12]`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen it doesn't just need to be monotonically increasing, it also needs an element after it that breaks the pattern.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Ah of course, I read past that part. Thanks. I'll fix my answer. Should actually save bytes. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 142 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
I>-ṣ0ṖS€ỊÐḟ‘ɓĠL€ḟ1,ɓ¹ƝÆPẠ$ÐfW;ɓLẋ<¥21W;ż@€"“æƥu®ụ³Km&|°ẓz“ṿ$¥{d3ɓFȤSJẎVḍnṃ*¹0Ḟ¬ȤɲƝċƲạB'ɼɓ.€⁺Ƒ“¢ßUṡʠx\~⁻ḅėʠAƓḳ¶e<“½ė!Ƙ¥Ḍ3]⁷ṀƭȮþċ⁽?ṫĠƁÆȦØ⁾Ż»ṣ€⁷¤
```

A monadic link accepting a list of integers, returning a list of lists of clickbaits (each of which is a list of characters and integers). For a full program printing line-feed separated clickbaits just add `ẎY` to the end.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU9dSwJBFP0thRTEFH6UEkpfD0HlQyAlUb5lD2G9BX0RbpFBVhgD6UPmWq4vmYRCzuyqwcw67Pov7vyRbeotDhy49x7OOXc/ncmceN7K3CTQNz/Qp4S8bIB1ywtAKjJbcrGtx39XpBJALmZUlHluHUzdxwt7yaiL42DmY8wIBpLRQXdBKUdl9pnXhXHEmmAZrL12MHbOPsHEp@oA9NvHjLPdkIuXnVpiFcyHTSD3h0CvJhj1A3lhDafmtkTZzosWmNWlcbfr4inlKzVTPCoL9sorG0CrQ/1450JqFpBruzjUFwUG0mZf6divpmcXR0SJGUDuQimpdYBmxYfT5H07L7XePNB3Wxcazzl1XpJaf2AxS/3/l9JhNY/fqGJbnrc9jUIoiAIKMyiMIoojaFZN4f9I/QA)** (Footer makes a single list of clickbaits and then separates them with new-lines.)
...or see **[the example](https://tio.run/##HY9PSwJRFMU/SyEFMYWj1Ubp3yKoXARSEuUuW4S1C/pHOEUGWWE8SBfZjOW4ySQU8r0ZNXhvfMzzW9z3RaZnXLiLc36ce@5hJps9C4K1hWkgH2EgL0l53QD3nhUBmzJXFsizEiMJm7omECW8wvKb4FghVjxIxQRKgFOIUzuip2KD7pIix2XuldW5fUKb4Nq0vXE0cUm/wUHnygDyG6L2xX5UoFW/llwH52kb8OMxkJspSsKA32jDr4kWr3gF3gKnujIpugLNqFxpOPxZRdB3Zm4BqQ6t070rabiAb73S0FrmCHCb/mTiI6bnlcZ4mdqAH6JpaXSA5PiX32R9ryCN3iKQT8/iBsv7dVaWRn/gUlf9/3@lQ2sBu1PFdoJgV9ciWlSbVVtXM6fNp/8A)** given in the question.

#### How?

The 99 right-most bytes of this Link form a nilad (a function with zero arguments, i.e. a constant):

```
“...“...“...“...»ṣ€⁷¤
                    ¤ - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
“...“...“...“...»     - list of compressed strings (the four clickbait-texts with the
                      -   integers replaced with line-feed characters)
                   ⁷  - literal line-feed character
                 ṣ€   - split-at for €ach (read to interweave with the integers)
```

Let's label these text-parts as `X`, now the Link is:

```
I>-ṣ0ṖS€ỊÐḟ‘ɓĠL€ḟ1,ɓ¹ƝÆPẠ$ÐfW;ɓLẋ<¥21W;ż@€"X - Link: list of integers Z
                                             - # get the monotonically increasing runs:
I                                            - incremental differences of Z
 >-                                          - greater than -1 (vectorises)
   ṣ0                                        - split at zeros
     Ṗ                                       - pop (discard final run)
      S€                                     - sum each (length - 1 for all runs)
         Ðḟ                                  - filter discard if:
        Ị                                    -   insignificant (discard any 0s or 1s)
           ‘                                 - increment (yielding all run-lengths >= 3)
            ɓ                                - new dyadic chain with that on the right
                                             - # get the multiplicities:
             Ġ                               - group indices of Z by value
              L€                             - length of €ach
                ḟ1                           - filter discard 1s
                  ,                          - pair with right (the run-lengths)
                   ɓ                         - new dyadic chain with that on the right
                                             - # get the prime-pairs
                     Ɲ                       - for each pair in Z
                    ¹                        -   identity (do nothing)
                          Ðf                 - filter keep if:
                         $                   -   last two links as a monad:
                      ÆP                     -     is prime? (vectorises)
                        Ạ                    -     all?
                            W                - wrap in a list
                             ;               - concatenate with right ([multiplicities,runs])
                              ɓ              - new dyadic chain with that on the right
                                             - # get top count as a list
                               L             - length
                                   21        - literal 21
                                  ¥          - last two links as a dyad
                                 <           -   less than? (1 if 20 or less, else 0)
                                ẋ            -   repeat ([length] if 20 or less, else [])
                                     W       - wrap in a list (i.e. [[length]] or [[]])
                                      ;      - concatenate with right ([[prime pairs],[multiplicities],[run-lengths]])
                                             - ...now we have [[length],[prime pairs],[multiplicities],[run-lengths]]
                                          "X - zip with X (the text-parts)
                                         €   -   for each (item in the current list):
                                       ż@    -     interleave with swapped arguments
```

Comment: Impressive! :P Didn't even use the sentences...wow

Comment: That is because Jelly has the ability to have compressed strings. The sentences are there in the `“...“...“...“...»` part of the code, with line feeds in place of the numbers -- [like this](https://tio.run/##AccAOP9qZWxsef//4oCcw6bGpXXCruG7pcKzS20mfMKw4bqTeuKAnOG5vyTCpXtkM8mTRsikU0rhuo5W4biNbuG5gyrCuTDhuJ7CrMikybLGncSLxrLhuqFCJ8m8yZMu4oKs4oG6xpHigJzCosOfVeG5ocqgeFx@4oG74biFxJfKoEHGk@G4s8K2ZTzigJzCvcSXIcaYwqXhuIwzXeKBt@G5gMatyK7DvsSL4oG9P@G5q8SgxoHDhsimw5jigb7Fu8K7/8OHxZLhuZj/)

Comment: That's a whole lotta Jelly...

Comment: Longest jelly golf I've seen. My answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152855/75553) comes close but still shorter by 16 bytes

Comment: @dylnan I [have](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122362/53748) a [few](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127430/53748) Jelly golfs which are longer, [a couple of which](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112750/53748) I think are [more impressive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127715/53748)

Comment: Wow, those are quite long

Comment: I think we should add the prize for longest Jelly program to Best of PPCG 2018.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>467</s> <s>457</s> <s>456</s> 453 bytes

```java
a->{int l=a.length,i=0,p=0,P=0,m[]=new int[999],t;String e=" Elements ",r=l<21?"The Top "+l+" Array"+e+"\n":"";for(;i<l;r+=i>0&&p(p)>1&p(t=a[i-1])>1?p+" And "+t+" Were Spotted Together, You Won't Believe What They Did\n":"",m[a[i++]]++)if(p<(p=a[i]))P++;else{r+=P>2?P+e+"Sort Themselves, Find Out What Comes Next\n":"";P=1;}for(;l-->0;r+=m[l]>1?"These "+m[l]+e+"Will Blow Your Mind\n":"");return r;}int p(int n){for(int i=2;i<n;n=n%i++<1?0:n);return n;}
```

Assumes the input-array will contain values `0 < N < 1000` (`[1,999]`).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pVRrT9swFP3Or7iKNEiIW@qkD9KQorHHN1glkNCU5UPWmmLmOJnjlqEqv51dJy2PCbp1KHUc177nnnt87Jt0kbZupj/uJyItSzhNuVzuAHCpmbpKJwzOzBDgXCsuZzCxcSZOIHVC/LvChr8zkBDBfdoaLXEWRJS2BZMzfU141CEFtjG2LE4iyW4NdBwEQUJ0uAJlkQWfBMuY1CVYREXiyKPH1sU1g4u8AMsVrgXvlUrvLJe51jdpDS0rvMqVHfIjESo34qPO7m5hF86IYqejNOYtmuDouDChcoogGr8umWJwXuRasyliz5i@ZorA13wOl7nc03DCBGcLBpfXqQYkcAcf@bRJiAUgrOsmies6/MoujuzCJEocZ@y6IRMlWyKV8cg7Hhua57mqIbKSiQUrCXzmyOPLXDfgH/KMlXDGfulVPeOIhlVdlGi1Rh1TVhaLZNQoUTIswYwN9CUXAk5EfmuYKzhF4AbECRXTcyVBhVVo9qIw@wXSWRpg88kjD0WToYzkOyzmiB53hvIhTIbVPUAx/y74BEqdauwWOZ9Chr6wm@2Kk9RpPGHMAhluvdlWM7BrVwAc7NcdwF7jgz2Y5WXJiyEE6wl9m0OhOGrwOLn0iF@tF5Ts55zJCXuc7kJMCS4h3WS9KJ9M5ko9XVYOwQebOpCi2B7YnlOv3T9oXHxXapa187luY3KphbSztmxP7LUxk@UqBb4pPj3Sr5xVVS8E/7Ve2n@9YKS67BFKK2L6numMAKSmvqR0gxgY2oPYBBOKRH1Cu0kddghxQx@JkwE5xBWbxeqC3XNIoxRZi@ZvK9ozJpi7R/5kgcW8RUevs1lHn3hGv0EtY61fjww2yVebqabXCOcbOQck@Adr1WoZ0QKw@4@iDbYVrYsSPbgMc9f5cdR//rxJN39LTh5u2nYZX9SJUqNQrYz5pJ3/MFSHbP16m8U2Xk00QGvT1Ync4jZZhb3pDglevxP7EJtz1jdnrPNwC/Qac6OZBngq/WRL0s8QyVMkbJ7xLIrdJ16f@JR0cTY4XBVY7VT3vwE)

```java
a->{                     // Method with integer-array parameter and String return-type
  int l=a.length,        //  Length of the input-array
      i=0,               //  Index-integer
      p=0,               //  Previous item, starting at 0
      P=0,               //  Sequence-counter, starting at 0
      m[]=new int[999],  //  Element-counter array, starting filled with 0s
      t;                 //  Temp-integer to reduce the byte-count
  String e=" Elements ", //  Temp-String " Elements " to reduce byte-count
         r=l<21?         //  If the size of the input-array is 20 or less:
            "The Top "+l+" Array"+e+"\n"
                         //    Start the result-String with 'length' gossip-line
           :             //   Else:
            "";          //    Start the result-String empty
  for(;i<l               //  Loop over the input-array
      ;                  //    After every iteration:
       r+=i>0&&          //     If this is not the first item,
           p(p)>1&p(t=a[i-1])>1?
                         //     and the current and previous items are both primes:
             p+" And "+t+" Were Spotted Together, You Won't Believe What They Did\n":"",
                         //      Append the 'two primes' gossip-line
       m[a[i++]]++)      //     Increase the counter of the current value by 1
    if(p<(p=a[i])        //   If the previous item is smaller than the current:
      P++;               //    Increase the sequence-counter by 1
    else{                //   Else:
      r+=P>2             //    If the sequence-counter is 3 or larger:
          P+e+"Sort Themselves, Find Out What Comes Next\n":"";
                         //     Append the 'sequence' gossip-line
      P=1;}              //    Reset the sequence-counter to 1
  for(;l-->0;            //  Loop over the Element-counter array
      r+=m[l]>1?         //   If this element occurred at least two times:
          "These "+m[l]+e+"Will Blow Your Mind\n":"");
                         //    Append the 'occurrence' gossip-line
  return r;}             //  Return the result

// Separated method to check if the given number is a prime
// If `n` is a prime, it remains the same; if not: either 1 or 0 is returned
int p(int n){for(int i=2;i<n;n=n%i++<1?0:n);return n;}
```

Answer (score 1):

- still golfing but help will be much appreciated

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 397 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(x=>(l<=x?s++:(s>2&&r.push(s+" Elements Sort Themselves, Find Out What Comes Next"),s=1),P(x)&&P(l)&&r.push(l+` And ${x} Were Spotted Together, You Won't Believe What They Did`),c[l=x]=-~c[x]),c=[s=l=r=[]])&&c.map((x,i)=>x>1&&c.indexOf(x)==i&&r.push(`These ${x} Elements Will Blow Your Mind`))&&[...r,...a[20]?[]:[`The Top ${a.length} Array Elements`]]
P=(n,i=1)=>n>1&&++i*i>n||n%i&&P(n,i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDbSgMxEIbvfYpBtCZuXGw9XIhZ8XinFhSKhMCG7bQbSZMlSWuKh1evWYUSGEjC/803865WKjRed/HIuiluZnyjeKXKhepI4hUxlzxdhaK4IKEaDQa@7JahJaHYhXuDC7QxwIvzEV5bXAQ0KwwMHrSdwvMywqRVEW7dAgM8YYq7lAU@pGxMEh0MxsTQLdAUNVzn1N5n@oYJeoSXzsWIU3h1c4wtegZvbgkTZw8i3KDRuMJ/fu68hjs9rSlrhOFJ8qOfRiSZr1wEbrjnQsrcqvkbiiSmKa9SNexfsimm51kW4lxvberMDPgvsx1zoo2BG@M@ehEPjzla04wVZVl6losSo2N5JeSF6PNZvMsEVRq089h@w7X3ar3F1VLujDmxTOeN8Mr2OkWhD3Vlv77svu73kz/ppnE2OIOlcXMyI2LIRuyEneY6zOeMnUtKdza/)

Comment: Could you save by replacing a single character like `'!'` with `' Elements '` (or similar)?

Comment: You've failed to correctly handle a right-hand monotonically increasing run with no trailing decrease (the link you give should not output "6 Elements Sort Themselves, Find Out What Comes Next", as there is no "Next")

Comment: Lack `The Top * Array Elements`

Comment: well this even shorter y code in my origin answer i did it this way. will be fixed. @l4m2 thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, because the sentence in the challenge description can be interpret two ways, but shouldn't `[5,10,5,10]` output the `These 2 Elements Will Blow Your Mind` twice? I think the challenge part "_Only print this once per unique number._" means the numbers `5` and `10`, not the number `N=2`. But perhaps ask OP to verify. If the second, your implementation is correct and the other three answers are incorrect. If the first only your implementation is incorrect.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen not from the way i understood it

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>351</s> <s>350</s> <s>349</s> 347 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map((x,i)=>c[s=x>=l?-~s:++s>2&&(t+=s+` Elements Sort Themselves, Find Out What Comes Next
`),P(x)&P(l)&&(t+=l+` And ${x} Were Spotted Together, You Won't Believe What They Did
`),l=x]=-~c[x],t=a[20]?'':`The Top ${a.length} Array Elements
`,c=[s=l=P=(n,i=n)=>n%--i?P(n,i):1/i])+c.map(x=>x>1&&(t+=`These ${x} Elements Will Blow Your Mind
`))&&t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDRasIwFIbvfYpzsWlKU7c6twtHKrrNu22CgoxSaKgHzUiT0kQXGfrqXbqCN@EEDt/5/v@bH7kpalHZSOktNgvWcJbwYckrQhwVAUuK1DCXMDmNLmYShiYZ9fvEhsyEObxJLFFZAytdW1jvsTQoj2goLITawufBwmbPLbzoEg18oLO9PKBL4oL@ksigA0kPmvntm193hg3WCKtKW4tbWOsd2j3WFL70ATZaDSzMUQo8Ysf1F0/wKrYtVTKXsehSpC6jlvF0dJ9NB4NJ7nc8qPJ4PpSodnZ/hlld89PVvpfTgvmUki0ZUVQw5WOr2ygS02X7DybxnciCsPivxbHEJXGn3sINdubXLjZCSphL/dNa1/Dum/B@PqxtngutjJY4lHpHFiSN6Yg@0LF/Y9rOj/SJjrMgaP4A)